What is the standard methodology for integrating ODE with inequality constraints?
How does one integrate a scalar ODE
$$\dot{x} = f(x)$$
subject to constraints $x \geq 0$ and $x \leq x_{\max}$?
In other words, the ODE can be rewritten using cases:
$$\dot{x} = \begin{cases}
0 & \mathrm{if} \; x = 0 \; \mathrm{and} \; f(x) < 0 \\
0 & \mathrm{if} \; x = x_{max} \; \mathrm{and} \; f(x) > 0 \\
f(x) & \mathrm{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$
I am aware that there are multiple off-the-shelf numerical libraries that solve such equations. However, I would like to understand how they do it. Is there an exact solution? What are the typical algorithms  used?
I want a definite integral
$$x(t) = x_0 + \int_0^t \dot{x}dt$$
where the starting value $x_0$ is guaranteed to lie within the constraints
Edit: To clear up the confusion about the purpose of this ODE, I will give an example. There is a heavy box in the middle of a 1D room. I can push or pull it with certain velocity. If I push it too much, it reaches a wall. Then, no matter how hard I push it, it will not move. Instead, I can pull the box away from that wall. I can keep pulling it, until I hit the other wall.

@SassatelliGiulio I am sorry, I do not know what a partial function is. What I am trying to achieve is best described by the 3 cases equation. If the inequalities $x \geq 0$ and $x \leq x_{\max}$ do not (formally) reflect that idea, please disregard them.

I'm sorry, I accidentally deleted your comment. Could a moderator please undelete the comment by @SassatelliGiulio?

If I understand well, you are considering a discontinuous differential equation of the form
$$
\dot x=\widetilde f(x):=\begin{cases}
0 ;;;;;;\text{if } x\leq 0 \text{ or } x\geq x_{max},\
f(x) ;;\text{otherwise}.
\end{cases}
$$
Now, the problem is that $\widetilde f:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ is discontinuous, and the existence results do not apply. A possible way out is to consider a generalized notion of solution, via ``embedding'' the discontinuous ODE in a differential inclusion. Check the keywords: Filippov/Krasowskii regularization/projected dynamical systems.

@MatteoDR Your dynamical system is not the same as I have written. Your dynamical system would arrive at x=0 or x=xmax, and stay there forever. The dynamical system I am interested in reaches x=0, and cannot go any lower, but can move back to higher values of x. Similarly, if the system reaches x=xmax, it cannot go any higher, but can go back to lower values

Ok, sorry, now what you had in mind is clearer . So, what your are mentioning about is exactely the projected dynamical system, check it out!
